# System of first order partial differential equation

Tags: optimization, difference-equations

I have following function -

$$ \max_{x, y} ~ u(x, y)^{3}x + (1-u(x, y))^{3}y$$

FOC:
$$u_{x}(3u(x, y)^{2}x - 3(1-u(x, y))^{2}y) +u(x,y)^{3} = 0$$... (1)

$$u_{y}(3u(x, y)^{2}x - 3(1-u(x, y))^{2}y) +(1-u(x,y))^{3} = 0$$... (2)

Can I solve it like -
Treat (1) as ode in x and (2) as ode in y  and solve them separately and then get u(x, y) = $sol_{(1)}*sol_{(2)}$

I just need clarification and guidance if I am wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your reasoning is correct. Some remarks:

- If you have an optimization problem, then you assume that you know the objective function, which in your case contains the function $u(x,y)$. As such, this function is known and you want to find the particular values $x^*$ and $y^*$ that maximizes your objective function. In other words, the optimal values $x^*$ and $y^*$ are unknowns but $u(x,y)$ itself is known. If you solve an ode, then the function itself is unknown.
- Next, notice that if you have an ode, like
  $$
  u_x(3u(x,y)2x−3(1−u(x,y))2y)+u(x,y)3=0
  $$
  Then you inherently assume that this equation holds for **all** values of $x$ and $y$ in the domain of $u$. In other words, you have an identity. [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(mathematics))
- On the other hand, if you derive the first order conditions for an optimization problem, then this first order condition will only hold at the particular (candidate) optimal points $x^\ast$ and $y^\ast$ but you will not get an identity that holds for all $x$ and $y$. As such, the methods used to solve ODE's are not suitable to solve first order conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am not maximizing for x and y. Some background to my problem - agent is trying signal x and y to the society through function u and he is trying to choose that x and y which will benefit him the most

Comment: I don't get it: If he chooses $x$ and $y$ that benefits him the most then he is indeed maximising for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: He is maximizing with $x$ and $y$, not $for$ $x$ and $y$